# Flutter permission_handler Doesnt ask for notification

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, permissions

I'm using firabase notifications. But before initialize it i want to ask user to get permission. But when i using permission_handler its not asking to user even i uninstall and reinstall app. How can i solve it ? its my code for ask it :

```
@override
  void initState() { 
    getPermissions();
}




    void getPermissions() async {
        var requestResult = await Permission.notification.request();
        var isPermissionGranted = await Permission.notification.isGranted;
        var isPermissionPermamentlyDenied =
            await Permission.notification.isPermanentlyDenied;

       //Its giving logs immediatly. Doesn't ask for permission.
        log("requestResult $requestResult");
        log("isPermissionGranted $isPermissionGranted");
        log("isPermissionPermamentlyDenied $isPermissionPermamentlyDenied");
```

Answer (score 1):

The following permissions will show no dialog:

Notification
Bluetooth
The following permissions will show no dialog, but will open the corresponding setting intent for the user to change the permission status:

manageExternalStorage
systemAlertWindow
requestInstallPackages
accessNotificationPolicy
link: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Answer (score 0):

Is your test device iOS or android?
If it's iOS, you have to configure in Xcode. Under `Signing & Capabilities`.
Add Push Notifications.

Comment: I'm testing it on real device android